# ROS2 compiled node release executable crashes when launched from a different computer

Tags: ros, ros2, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- OS : Windows 10 x64 PRO
- ROS 2 distribution : Foxy Fitzroy (precompiled)

##Issue :

- On the PC my node is developed on, the .EXE from build/Release runs perfectly. I don't need to source ROS2, just launching the node works.
- On the second PC I want to deploy the node, I have the ros2 Foxy binaries set up at the same exact location, and Path set up properly. However, when I run the node in the same way on this PC, the node crashes instantly, shutting down as soon as it is launched.

I can confirm that the shared ros2 libraries (rclcpp.dll, rcl.dll and such) are found at the Path, as when I remove ros2-foxy/bin from it, I get this error message.

---

*Note : sourcing ROS2 is not an option for me. It must work without this step.*
*Edit : even if I source ROS2 on my second PC, it still crashes.*

Therefore the question is : **how to make it run on the second PC as it runs on the first?**

Thank you very much, any help is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366803/ros2-compiled-node-release-executable-crashes-when-launched-from-a-different-computer/) by [f.stojanovic](https://answers.ros.org/users/59244/f.stojanovic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-02**:\

> I get this error message.

I assume you intended to post a screenshot.

Seeing as this is Windows, that's probably the only/best way to show the crash dialog, so I've given you sufficient karma to be able to attach images.

For console text, please do not post screenshots. Instead, copy-paste the text into your question.

**Comment by [f.stojanovic](https://answers.ros.org/users/59244/f.stojanovic/) on 2020-12-02**:
@gvdhoorn, thank you for your answer. Yes, that error message is not important as it is controlled, only arises when I intentionally hide my ros2 distribution.

The way my node crashes when deploying on a target (second PC) is not verbose, the console just shuts down the same instant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution : the target (second) PC only had the binary distribution installed.

**This is not sufficient to run ROSv2 nodes**.

The whole process must be followed, especially installing VS dependencies, as well as cmake and python packages.

P.S. : don't bother with RQT if you have the same issue as described above (it is not well-ported to Windows anyway).

---

Originally posted by [f.stojanovic](https://answers.ros.org/users/59244/f.stojanovic/) with karma: 11 on 2020-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0